# How to pass validators as required inside form array angular?

Tags: html, angular, formarray, form-control

I need to make all the objects for skills as required. How can I achieve this?

```
this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
      applicantId: [''],
      comments: [''],
      recommendation: [''],
      skills: this.fb.array(
        this.skills.map((t) => {
          this.fb.control(t);
        })
      ),
    });
```

I need to make the skills as required for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the skills formArray as required, and then all the skills in it will be required
like this:

```
this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
  applicantId: [''],
  comments: [''],
  recommendation: [''],
  skills: this.fb.array(
    this.skills.map((t) => {
      this.fb.control(t);
    }), {validators: Validators.required}
  ),
});
```

or in formControl specific

```
 this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
  applicantId: [""],
  comments: [""],
  recommendation: [""],
  skills: this.fb.array(
    this.skills.map((t) => {
      this.fb.control(t, { validators: [Validators.required] });
    })
  ),
});
```

i suggest reading formBuilder documentation

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms